# How to perform outer join in Hsql

Tags: java, hibernate, informix, hsqldb

I have a query like this

```
SELECT * from table1 t1,table2 t2, OUTER table3 t3
```

This works in Informix database but when I use it as Hsql then it is not able to find this
"OUTER" keyword only... How to do outer join in Hibernate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HSQLDB supports Standard SQL syntax, which is different from your Informix syntax query. Some examples of this syntax:

```
SELECT * from table1 t1 NATURAL JOIN table2 t2 NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3

SELECT * from table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON (T1.X = T2.Y) LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON (T2.Z = T3.X)
```

You should adapt your query to the Standard syntax.

The query you reported in comments is translated to Standard SQL this way:

```
SELECT distinct sd.student_id, ss.sports_id, sf.fee_desc FROM STUDENTDETAILS sd
JOIN STUDENTSPORTS ss ON ss.sports_id = sd.sports_id LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENTFEES sf 
ON ???
```

Note you need a condition for the question marks. For example the id in STUDENTSFEES which needs to be equal to the id in STUDENTSSPORTS. sf.some_id = ss.some_id

Comment: The query which i have in my Informix syntax query is select sd.student_name,ss.student_sports,sf.student_fees from STUDENTDETAILS sd, STUDENTSPORTS ss,OUTER STUDENTFEES sf.... How will i write this in HSQLDB?

Comment: Can you report the full query? What you have reported does not make sense.

Comment: SELECT distinct sd.student_id,
  ss.sports_id,
  sf.fee_desc
  FROM STUDENTDETAILS sd, STUDENTSPORTS ss, OUTER STUDENTFEES sf
  WHERE ss.sports_id = sd.sports_id

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have your entities and mapping files set up correctly it would be a pretty straightforward "left outer join entity.field as alias"

from the HQL website

```
from Cat as cat
inner join cat.mate as mate
left outer join cat.kittens as kitten
```

[HQL website](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

In your case taking the tables as entities it would be something like
    from table1 as tab1
    inner join tab.table2column as tab2
    left outer join tab.table3 column as tab3

Comment: Hello Brian, I refered to the document and created my query like this from Table as table left outer join table.column as column but i got error that table is not in schema....

Comment: are the objects that you are querying on in the solution with the correct hibernate xml mapping file?  From what you've written it sounds like you need at least two classes that correspond to table1 and table2 and two xml mapping files with the first having a bag (or set maybe) of the second as one of its parameters.   I always get bags and sets confused but to get it working it shouldn't matter much at this point.

Answer (score 0):

HQL and SQL are two different languages. SQL uses tables and columns, and HQL uses entities, fields and associations between entities.

Read the [Hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/).

Comment: I know that are two different languages.since i am using HQL,in that i am using named native query and i am populating the result set to a pojo class fields, I just wanted to know wot HQL query will be equivalent to my mentioned SQL query

Comment: HQL works on entities. Show us your entities. BTW, I don't know this outer SQL syntax, but it seems that there is no join at all in the SQL query.